# transferring data through tcp sockets on a remote server using nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, tcp

I’m building a Nodejs TCP module, a server/client application to send data through tcp sockets. I have this module working on my localhost with no issues but when I send data from my localhost to a remote server It doesn’t work. I’m getting weird results because I can see the header of my data in my nginx access logs, so I know the data is being transferred but my server side application isn’t saving the data as expected. I’m clearly missing something. I’ve tried playing around with the ip-addresses and a few nginx-conf files I found online but have had no success. I’m not sure if I need to open a port or manipulate a firewall but any help is greatly appreciated Here’s the node app and my nginx.conf files.

## TCP Client App

```
/* Dependencies */
var server_external_ip = '77.77.77.277'
var fs = require('fs');
var hl7 = require('simple-hl7');
/* Build TCP Server */
var server = hl7.Server;
var tcpClient = server.createTcpClient();
/* Connection */
tcpClient.connect('127.0.0.1', 6969);
/* Get XML  */
var msg = fs.readFileSync('./data/example.xml').toString();
/* Send Message */
setTimeout(function() {
    tcpClient.send(msg, function(ack) {
      console.log("ACK: ",ack.toString());
      console.log("\nsuccessful transfer");
      tcpClient.close();
    });
}, 500);
```

## the server can be found here, [click here](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/148120/A-simple-node-js-HL7-MLP-server--Saves-m) but heres the config code..

```
  /*
      Config class
      vars:
      baseFolder: Where to save the messages
      port      : What port to listen on
      ip        : what ip to listen on
  */
  var Config = new function() {
      this.baseFolder = "data";
      this.port = 6969;
      this.ip = '127.0.0.1';
  }
```

## heres the nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

## in my sites-enabled directory

```
upstream backend_nodejs {
  # hash $remote_addr consistent;
  server 192.168.1.41:9696;
  keepalive 512;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  client_max_body_size 16M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;

  location / {
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass http://backend_nodejs;
  }

}
```

## and finally heres an example of my nginx access log

```
xx.xx.xx.123 - - [11/Mar/2016:16:18:27 -0800] "Connection Established" 400 172 "-" "-" "-"
```

Answer (score 0):

You messing up together tcp and http. You client <--> server connection has nothing to do with nginx at all. It is purely nodejs <--> nodejs thing. You probably just missing firewall configuration. Firewall is not nginx.

Also you have `var server_external_ip = '77.77.77.277'` But you trying to connect locally `tcpClient.connect('127.0.0.1', 6969);` It should be `tcpClient.connect('77.77.77.277', 6969);`

Comment: Ok, so your saying I'm using websockets?  if I wanted to use nodejs to send data thought TCP sockets should I something like use this? ( look at net.connect() ) http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_net_module.htm @Sergey Yarotskiy